Prove that $\sigma(\overline A)$ covered by $\cup_{i=1}^n B(\lambda_i, \Sigma_A(\overline A)).$
Let $A\in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ and perturbed matrix $\overline{A}\in \mathbb C^{n,n}.$ Suppose spectrum of A, $\sigma(A)=\{ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\}$  and $\sigma(\overline A)=\{ \overline\lambda_1,\overline\lambda_2,...,\overline\lambda_n\}.$
Spectral variation of $\overline A$ with respect to $A$ given by
$$\Sigma_A(\overline A)=\max_i\min _j |\overline \lambda_i-\lambda_j|.$$
Hausdorff distance between the spectrum is defined as the $max\{\Sigma_A(\overline A),\Sigma_{\overline A}(A)\}.$

Prove that $\sigma(\overline A)$ covered by $\cup_{i=1}^n B(\lambda_i,
 \Sigma_A(\overline  A)).$

My attempt:
Let $\overline \lambda_j \in \sigma(\overline A).$ It is enough to prove that $\overline \lambda_j \in B(\lambda_i,
 \Sigma_A(\overline  A)),$ for some $i$.
Consider $\Sigma_A(\overline  A)=\max_j \min_i |\overline \lambda_j-\lambda_i|.$ This shows that  there exists $\lambda_k$ such that $\min_i |\overline \lambda_j-\lambda_i|=|\overline \lambda_j-\lambda_k|$.$
|\lambda_k-\overline \lambda_j| \leq \max_j|\lambda_k-\overline \lambda_j|=\Sigma_A(\overline  A).$ That is $ \lambda_j \in B(\lambda_k,
 \Sigma_A(\overline  A))\subset \cup_{i=1}^n B(\lambda_i,
 \Sigma_A(\overline  A)).$ Hence, the spectrum of $\overline  A$ is covered by $\cup_{i=1}^n B(\lambda_i,
 \Sigma_A(\overline  A)).$ Am I correct?

This is fine, up to a typo and some wonky notation. The $\lambda_j$ should be an $\overline{\lambda}_j$, and writing $|\lambda_k - \overline{\lambda}_j| \le \max_j |\lambda_k - \overline{\lambda}_j|$ is wonky, because you are using $j$ as both a fixed and dummy variable. But, I understand the thrust of the argument, and it is fine.

Thank you very much :)
